# Accessing private members of object from outside the class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I´ve defined a class like this:

```
function Class1(){
   function Func1(){
     /* Methods and vars */
   };

   Funcs = new Array();

   this.appendAction = new function(ArgFunc){
      Funcs.push(ArgFunc);
   };
};

Object1 = new Class1();

function OutFunc(){
    /* Defining commands here */
};
Object1.appendAction(OutFunc);
```

My question is whether is there a way or not to access the private members of Object1, say Func1(), in the scope of the function OutFunc(), for the sake that this function is now an element of the array Funcs of Object1.

Comment: Why would you want to access a private variable of an outside function? Did you consider Setters and Getters? That is the best alternative

Comment: Well, let's say that the class is a handler of functions defined in a library, so those functions are further processed, but not spontaneously executed. Anyway, I want to know if it is possible to access the elements of the class this way without any additional fix or rearrangement of Class1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of weird, but with minimal change to your code I will do something like that :

```
function Class1(){
    function Func1(){
        /* Methods and vars */
    };

    Funcs = new Array();

    this.appendAction = new function(ArgFunc){
       Funcs.push(function() { return ArgFunc(Func1); });
    };
};

Object1 = new Class1();

function OutFunc(func1){
    /* Defining commands here */
    func1();
};
Object1.appendAction(OutFunc);
```

But really it's probably not a good way to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, Anyway, I am able to do so.

Comment: Hum... if you are able to modify Class1, why no just set Func1 as 'public', simply adding : this.Func1 = Func1. In function Class1(). That will not broke any code